# How to limit returned results of a JOIN query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-limit

I am trying to limit the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT expense.*, transaction.* FROM expense
INNER JOIN transaction ON expense_id = transaction_expense_id
```

What I want to do, is limit the number of 'parent' rows. IE. if I do a LIMIT 1, I would receive only one expense item, but still get all transactions associated with it.

How would this be achieved? I am using MySQL 5.0

At this stage, if I do LIMIT 1, I get one expense, and only one transaction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So assuming we can exclude the user table, it could be rewritten as:

```
select * from expense, transaction where expense_id = transaction_expense_id
```

Now if you want to apply a limit, you could do it like this:

```
select * from expense, transaction where expense_id = transaction_expense_id and 
  expense_id in (select expense_id from expense limit 1)
```

Would that do what you wanted? Obviously you need to be cautious about what order your expense_ids are going to come back in, so you probably want to use ORDER BY whatever.

Edit: Given the MySQL limitation described in your comment below, maybe this will work:

```
select * from (select id from expense order by WHATEVER limit 1) as t1, transaction where expense_id=transaction_expense_id;
```

Ben

Comment: "#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'" Server version: 5.0.27-community-nt

Comment: Subquery is the Right Way to do this. You've hit a MySQL limitation; either upgrade (to 5.1, which might fix this, or to Postgres). Otherwise you'll have to consider a non-pure SQL solution or something really hideous.

Comment: Marking as accepted answer because it would work in another SQL environment.

Comment: @rixth: Thanks. I've also added another possible solution that might work for you...

Comment: :-) That's good news! BTW: This might be entirely unhelpful, but I wonder if you might want to consider renaming your columns in your tables? If you renamed expense_id to just id then you could refer to it as expense.id or just id (when it's unambiguous) instead. It may help make things easier...

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to specify which **expense** item you want to get. The most expensive? The newest? Then join against a subquery that returns only that:

```
SELECT
    expense.*, transaction.*, user.*
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM expense WHERE ...) AS expense
INNER JOIN
    transaction ON expense_id = transaction_expense_id
```

Comment: What if I wanted to say, return 10 expense items (with associated transactions)

Comment: @rixth: this uses as many expense items as the subquery will return.

Comment: @Tom Change it to `WHERE ... LIMIT 10) AS expense`. I think.

Answer (score 2):

Since upgrading the SQL server is not an option, I may end up doing two queries.

```
expenses = SELECT * FROM expense ... LIMIT x
foreach expenses as expense
    expense.transactions = SELECT * FROM transacion WHERE transaction_expense_id = expense.expense_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old... came across this in a search and thought I'd add a couple thoughts, given the inability to use limit in a subquery...

```
select e.expense_id, transaction.* 
from (select max(expense_id) from expense) e 
    inner join transaction t ON e.expense_id = t.transaction_expense_id
```

or if you want to have all columns from `expense` and not just `expense_id` you could nest subqueries.

```
select e.*, t.*
from (
     select e1.*
     from expense e1 inner join (select max(expense_id) from expense) e2
        on e1.expense_id = e2.expense_id
     ) e  inner join transaction t on e.expense_id = t.transaction_expense_id
```