# Limit this JOIN query so one result for each left-side table is returned?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

```
Person:
+----+-------+
| ID | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Frank |
+----+-------+

Position:
+----+---------+----------+------------+
| ID | name    | personID | startDate  |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
|  1 | Cashier | 1        | 2013-01-01 |
|  2 | Manager | 1        | 2013-04-23 |
|  3 | Cashier | 2        | 2014-02-01 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
```

The `Position` table tracks various positions that a person has held.

How can I create a listing that shows each person and their current position (which would be whatever position has the latest start date)? Essentially I need to limit the `JOIN` of the `Position` table to only return one result.

I tried the following code.

```
SELECT p.id, h.positionID FROM person p JOIN position h ON p.id = h.personID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LIMITing an SQL JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494974/limiting-an-sql-join)

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: @JamesHunt That seems to be asking for the opposite, limiting the left side of the table. I want to limit the right side.

Comment: @Gunaseelan I don't have much beyond the normal join. I've messed around with subqueries but keep hitting a wall. `SELECT p.id, h.positionID FROM person p
JOIN position h ON p.id = h.personID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following :-

```
select p.ID, pp.name PersonName, p.name PositionName ,p.startDate 
from Position p
inner join
(select personID, max(startDate) sdate from Position group by personID) as a
on p.personID = a.personID and p.startDate = a.sdate
left join Person pp
on pp.ID = p.personID
```

Yet, it is highly advised that you post the code that you tried.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acaddc/3)**

Comment: I made the `left join` to `inner join` to get one result each.