# apply a LIMIT to SQL INNER JOIN query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

**CATEGORY**

```
    id(int)
    1000  
    1001
```

**BOOK**

```
    id(int)  category(int) rating(float)
    3000     1000          5.0
    3001     1000          4.8
    3002     1000          3.0
    3003     1000          4.9
    3004     1001          4.9
    3005     1001          3.0
```

What I want to do is take the 3 top rated books from each category. After looking around and following the answer given at [LIMITing an SQL JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494974/limiting-an-sql-join), I tried this query.

```
    SELECT * FROM book, category WHERE book.category=category.id AND book.id IN (SELECT book.id FROM book ORDER BY rating LIMIT 3)
```

But it gives the following error

```
     #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

The solution said a minimum of **MySQL 5.1** was required, and I'm running **libmysql - 5.1.73**. What might be wrong?

Comment: I just mentioned it because I am running this query from a PHP script. I've removed it, sorry. :)

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql. You should rank the rows partitioning them by category and select the ones with rank <= 3 - unfortunately, MySQL does not have any ready syntax for that, unlike PostgreSQL, Oracle or MS SQL, so some workarounds are necessary.

Comment: I need to run the same query on 2 databases, and one of them is in Android, which uses SQLite. Can I do it there?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is complaining about the `IN`, not about the `LIMIT`. Change the `IN` to `INNER JOIN` and it should work.

Something like this query:

```
SELECT * FROM book b, category INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM book ORDER BY rating LIMIT 3) v
ON b.id=v.id
WHERE b.category=category.id;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a beginner in SQL, and I tried replacing the IN with INNER JOIN even though it seemed like the syntax was wrong and the error was this.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN (SELECT book.id FROM book ORDER BY rating LIMIT 3) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: This error is given

`#1054 - Unknown column 'book.category' in 'where clause' `

Comment: Edited the answer, but to help you writing a proper query, we need to know your table structure.

Comment: Thanks. The **BOOK** table contains more fields, but I believe they are not of any use because in this query, I only consider the rating and category.

Comment: Also, the query you suggested gives the following error

`#1054 - Unknown column 'b.book.id' in 'on clause' `

Comment: Oops, typo, sorry. I think it should work now, I have not time to copy your schema and test it myself right now.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support `LIMIT` in subqueries for certain subquery operators:

```
'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

**For example**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1
    ->   WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1);
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Read subquery [limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

Comment: OP already knows about that error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to do it just change `LIMIT 3` to `LIMIT 0,3` : like this :

```
 SELECT * FROM book, category WHERE book.category=category.id 
        AND book.id IN (SELECT book.id FROM book ORDER BY rating LIMIT 0,3)
```

[Source](http://blog.developpez.com/james-poulson/p10023/code/utilisation_d_un_limit_dans_une_sous_req) ^^

Comment: OP wants to _"take the 3 top rated books from **each** category"_

Comment: This doesn't work. The same error is given.

Comment: @SuhairZain can you post your query in a comment after changing limit?

Comment: I did the query exactly like you suggested.

`SELECT * FROM book, category WHERE book.category=category.id 
        AND book.id IN (SELECT book.id FROM book ORDER BY rating LIMIT 0,3)`